# Why does program count one extra value (cycle "while")?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why the program count one more value? For example, I give him N = 50. It gives out:

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
```

Code:

```
N = int(input())

n = 1
 
k = 1

while n < N:

    n = k ** 2
    print(n)
    k = k + 1
```

Comment: Could you update your question and include what you are trying to do exactly.

Comment: You're checking the limit *before* you calculate the power.

Comment: Simply put, in the example: 49 < 50, so the loop starts again once more

Comment: oh. Thanks. I understand)

Answer (score 3):

As explained, you're checking n then changing n, you want to change n then check before continuing.

You can use the [walrus operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)  to assign `n` and check it's value all in the while statement. *(requires Python 3.8+)*

```
N = int(input())
n = 1
k = 1

while (n := k**2) < N:
    print(n)
    k += 1
```

This essentially assigns `n` to `k**2` then checks if that result is `<N` before continuing.

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
```

Comment: could use more of an explanation

Comment: I edited, but how would I go more into depth? It's pretty straight forward. @KetZoomer

Answer (score 2):

Your program outputs `1 4 9 16 25 36 49 64` if your input is `50` because the `while`` loop is checking the value *before* you increase it.  Once in the loop, you increase it, calculate the square and then print.

If you want it to terminate, try setting calculating `n` as the last step in the loop:

```
N = int(input())

n = 1
 
k = 1

while n < N:

    
    print(n)
    k = k + 1
    n = k ** 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You're checking whether you reached the limit before you calculate the square and print it. So you're checking the previous value of `n`, not the one that's about to be printed.

Move the check inside the loop.

```
while True:
    n = k ** 2
    if n >= N:
        break
    print(n)
    k += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The `n < N` is evaluated *after* you've changed (and printed) `n`.

```
n = 1
k = 1

N=50

while 1:
    n = k ** 2
    if n > N:
        break
    print(n)
    k = k + 1
```

To fix this, break *before* you print, moving the evaluation inside the loop rather than *after the last update* of `n`

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
```

Answer (score 1):

With the condition of your code, for example, when `n = 49`, The condition is fulfilled because `49 < 50` therefore it will continue to process the value and print the new one. But once `n = 64` which is `> 50`, it stops. This is a possible solution:

```
N = int(input())
n = 1
k = 1

while True:
    if n >= N:
        break

    n = k ** 2
    print(n)
    k = k + 1
```

This will continuously execute the code but once the condition is met that `n >= N`, it will stop executing.